# Docker swarm with nginx as cache: 502 bad gateway

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-swarm

I've used Docker swarm for creating a cluster composed by 1 manager and 2 worker, everyone on vm (created by docker-machine).
i've created a "cdn service"  that caches, or pass request to backend (a tomcat container, on port 8080).
My docker version is 1.13-rc2

This is config file of my nginx image:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_zone:10m inactive=60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri";
proxy_cache_methods GET HEAD POST;
proxy_cache_valid 200 206 100m;
proxy_ignore_headers Set-Cookie;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Range'; 
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  172.17.0.1;

    #charset koi8-r;
    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/log/host.access.log  main;

location =  /example-av1.mpd {
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';

    proxy_cache my_zone;
    add_header X-Proxy-Cache             $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;

    proxy_set_header Host                $host;

    proxy_pass http://172.17.0.1:8700/shaka-player-master/media/example-av1.mpd;
  }

}
```

the problem is the following:
I've created overlay network named "mynet"

when i create service:

```
docker service create --name nginx-cdn --network mynet --mode global --publish mode=host,target=80,published=9500,protocol=tcp *myimage*
```

assuming that my cluster nodes are 192.168.99.103-104-105, and service is on port 9500, 
If i point to `192.168.99.103` (or 104, or 105) `:9500/example-av1.mpd` there is a 502 bad gateway, instead of redirect request to backend.

This problem appairs also with docker version 1.12.

How shoud i solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure your environment, but 172.17.0.1 seems to be a default bridge network and maybe not overlay. Can you provide the `docker network create` command which created `mynet` and the result of `docker network inspect mynet`?

Comment: I think you have right.. i would to a thing but i dont know how do to. I think i should attach tomcat (simply) container to mynet overlay (swarm scoped) network, but i dont know how, because of my cluster's nodes are inside VMs, while tomcat container runs in host.

Comment: this is output of docker network inspect mynet:   Config": [
  {"Subnet": "10.0.0.0/24",
       "Gateway": "10.0.0.1"
}
    ]
"IPv4Address": "10.0.0.4/24",
"Peers": [ {
  "Name": "manager-dash-b31a241cf6f1",
 "IP": "192.168.99.103"
 }, {  "Name": "worker-dash-2-fa841786e929",
 "IP": "192.168.99.105"
}, }  "Name": "worker-dash-1-50bff3c1087a",
  "IP": "192.168.99.104"  and other stuff i can't show here because of space. You have to know what this command is inside a vm. From host, i don't see this network. You can see 3 peers (1 vm-manager, and 2 vm-workers) inside mynet.

Answer (score 1):

`172.17.0.1` seems to be a default bridge network and maybe not overlay. If the backend container is running on a another single host, nginx container can connect with the private or global IP of the host instead of the bridge one.

If you want to join the backend container to the same swarm cluster, you can create overlay network with:

```
docker network create --driver overlay --subnet x.x.x.x/24 foo
```

and then create services in the same overlay network:

```
docker service create --network foo ... --name nginx nginx 
docker service create --network foo ... --name tomcat tomcat
```

You also need update proxy_pass in the nginx.conf:

```
proxy_pass http://tomcat:8700/shaka-player-master/media/example-av1.mpd;
```

The docs for overlay network is as follows:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/

Comment: i cannot to that. Because i want to have 3 vm with inside my cdn service, and another vm with inside tomcat. I know that i should create a tomcat container or a tomcat service. For communication between these services, i need that these services belong to same overlay network. But how, if from another VM i don't see "mynet" created from another VM?

Comment: If the tomcat container is running on a another single host, why not try to connect with the private or global IP of the host instead of the bridge one?